# How to copy directory that's injected as Resource?

Tags: java, spring

My Spring application has a Maven dependency on `app-resources.jar` which contains the directory `app-resources` (as well as the META-INF dir, which I don't care about).

I need to copy the full contents of that folder, without knowing the list of contained files and subfolders.

My first instinct was to try, at runtime, to inject the folder as a Spring resource :

```
// This is actually injected from app-resources.jar
@Value("classpath:/app-resources/")
private Resource appResource;

/** Copies the static resources to the NFS target folder. */
private void publishResources(final File targetPath) {
    File appResourceDir = getFileFromResource???(appResource);
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(appResourceDir, targetPath);
}
```

But I couldn't find a way to *view* that Resource as a directory. I also considered injecting the jar itself as a resource, and unpacking it (using a GzipInputStream). But I don't know if that is possible either.

Does anyone have a good solution to that problem ? Compile-time solutions (using maven) are welcome too.

EDIT to reply to a comment. The architecture of this application is a bit unusual but it's not in my power to change. We have a frontend project that generates a static html/js website at compile time (that's what the app-resources.jar is). At runtime we want to publish multiple instances of this static site, each with different data files (so we copy the static content, and put specific data files in the site's data/ directory).

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You could always look at this plugin jetspeed-unpack-maven-plugin.

Comment: @TedTrippin I added more info about "why?" to my question. That plugin could indeed be a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the cuff answer,  perhaps you could get the full class path.

```
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

You can then parse out the path for the jar you are interested in and then unzip the required paths to your desired directory.

Comment: The application will be running in an app server (Tomcat). Won't I run into rights/security issues by doing this ?

Comment: your app will have access to the file system based on the user that its running as.  It will certainly have read access to the jars,  and I would expect based on your question should have write access to wherever you plan to write the output to.